# How can I hide a WebGrid column based on the current user's role?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, webgrid

I need to do a grid using webgrid and I would like to hide the column (header and items) of edit actions based on user role.

How can I do that with webgrid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a helper method which would generate the columns dynamically based on user roles:

```
public static class GridExtensions
{
    public static WebGridColumn[] RoleBasedColumns(
        this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, 
        WebGrid grid
    )
    {
        var user = htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.User;
        var columns = new List<WebGridColumn>();

        // The Prop1 column would be visible to all users
        columns.Add(grid.Column("Prop1"));

        if (user.IsInRole("foo"))
        {
            // The Prop2 column would be visible only to users
            // in the foo role
            columns.Add(grid.Column("Prop2"));
        }
        return columns.ToArray();
    }
}
```

and then in your view:

```
@{
    var grid = new WebGrid(Model);
}
@grid.GetHtml(columns: grid.Columns(Html.RoleBasedColumns(grid)))
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll to use that idea